# About the usage of `||` in erlang

Tags: erlang

I am reading the source code of project `recon`,
i find an interesting code:

```
proc_attrs(binary_memory, Pid) ->
    case process_info(Pid, [binary, registered_name,
                            current_function, initial_call]) of
        [{_, Bins}, {registered_name,Name}, Init, Cur] ->
            {ok, {Pid, binary_memory(Bins), [Name || is_atom(Name)]++[Init, Cur]}};
        undefined ->
            {error, undefined}
    end;
```

in this code, there has a `[Name || is_atom(Name)]`,

I am try in the shell:

```
27> [a || is_atom(a)].
[a]
28> [a || is_atom("a")].
[]
29> [a || true].
[a]
30> [a || false].
[]
```

But i never see the usage like this, who can tell me the detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[ ... || ... ]` is a [list comprehension](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html), normally used to operate on a list to produce another list. In this case, only the filter portion of the generator side (right side) of the comprehension is being used, as a conditional, and as always the left side produces a value only if the filters pass. Consider your example:

```
27> [a || is_atom(a)].
[a]
28> [a || is_atom("a")].
[]
```

In command 27, `a` is indeed an atom, so the filter `is_atom/1` passes and so the left side produces the value `[a]`. But in command 28, the `is_atom/1` filter eliminates the value `"a"` since it's not an atom, the left side produces nothing, so the result is an empty list.

This approach is a shorthand way of writing a longer conditional. For example, the following code you cite from recon:

```
[Name || is_atom(Name)]++[Init, Cur]
```

could also be written as:

```
case is_atom(Name) of true -> [Name]; false -> [] end ++ [Init, Cur]
```

One could argue the latter is easier to understand, but clearly it's also more verbose and so may clutter the code too much.

Comment: Other question, the filter portion must be `build-in` functuon just like `is_atom, is_list`? Can i use a user defined function which return true or false?

Comment: Yes, in this case a filter can be a user-defined function that returns a boolean.